# How can I access quantity of individual items in my html?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

I think I need to add another field in Cart method. Can I do it without altering my models. If no then how should I improve my model

**models.py**

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save, post_delete


from products.models import Variation
# Create your models here.


class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey("Cart")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Variation)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    line_item_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.title

    def remove(self):
        return self.item.remove_from_cart()


def cart_item_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    qty = instance.quantity
    if qty >= 1:
        price = instance.item.get_price()
        line_item_total = Decimal(qty) * Decimal(price)
        instance.line_item_total = line_item_total

pre_save.connect(cart_item_pre_save_receiver, sender=CartItem)



def cart_item_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.cart.update_subtotal()

post_save.connect(cart_item_post_save_receiver, sender=CartItem)

post_delete.connect(cart_item_post_save_receiver, sender=CartItem)



class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, through=CartItem)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=25.00)
    tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0.145)
    tax_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=25.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=25.00)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def update_subtotal(self):
        print "updating..."
        subtotal = 0
        items = self.cartitem_set.all()
        for item in items:
            subtotal += item.line_item_total
        self.subtotal = "%.2f" %(subtotal)
        self.save()



def do_tax_and_total_receiver(sender, instance , *args, **kwargs):
    subtotal = Decimal(instance.subtotal)
    tax_total = round(subtotal * Decimal(instance.tax_percentage), 2)
    total = round(subtotal + Decimal(tax_total), 2)
    instance.tax_total = "%.2f" %tax_total
    instance.total = "%.2f" %(total)


pre_save.connect(do_tax_and_total_receiver, sender=Cart)
```

I am currently getting all the items but not there quantity 
**html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for object in object_list %}

<li>
{{ object.id }}
{{ object.cart.items.all }}

</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py for the Cart App**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin 

# Create your views here.
from orders.forms import GuestCheckoutForm
from orders.mixins import CartOrderMixin
from orders.models import UserCheckout, Order
from products.models import Variation
from .models import Cart, CartItem

class ItemCountView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")       
            if cart_id == None:
                count = 0
            else:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                count = cart.items.count()
            request.session["cart_item_count"] = count
            return JsonResponse({"count": count})   
        else:
            raise Http404   



class CartView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    model = Cart
    template_name = "carts/view.html"

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session.set_expiry(0) #5 minutes
        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")
        if cart_id == None:
            cart = Cart()
            cart.save()
            cart_id = cart.id
            self.request.session["cart_id"] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            cart.user = self.request.user
            cart.save()
        return cart

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cart = self.get_object()
        item_id = request.GET.get("item")
        delete_item = request.GET.get("delete", False)
        item_added = False
        if item_id:
            item_instance = get_object_or_404(Variation, id=item_id)
            qty = request.GET.get("qty", 1)
            try:
                if int(qty) < 1:
                    delete_item = True
            except:
                raise Http404
            cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item=item_instance)
            if created:
                item_added = True
            if delete_item:
                cart_item.delete()
            else:
                cart_item.quantity = qty
                cart_item.save()
            if not request.is_ajax():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
                #return cart_item.cart.get_absolute_url()

        if request.is_ajax():
            try:
                total = cart_item.line_item_total
            except:
                total = None
            try:
                subtotal = cart_item.cart.subtotal
            except:
                subtotal = None

            try:
                cart_total = cart_item.cart.total
            except:
                cart_total = None

            try:
                tax_total = cart_item.cart.tax_total
            except:
                tax_total = None    


            try:
                total_items = cart_item.cart.items.count()
            except:
                total_items = 0 

            data = {
                    "deleted": delete_item, 
                    "item_added": item_added,
                    "line_total": total,
                    "subtotal": subtotal,
                    "cart_total": cart_total,
                    "tax_total": tax_total,
                    "total_items": total_items
                    }

            return JsonResponse(data) 


        context = {
            "object": self.get_object()
        }
        template = self.template_name
        return render(request, template, context)


class CheckoutView(CartOrderMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
        model = Cart
        template_name = "carts/checkout_view.html"
        form_class = GuestCheckoutForm

        #def get_order(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #       cart = self.get_object() 
        #       new_order_id = self.request.session.get("order_id")
        #       if new_order_id is None:
        #           new_order = Order.objects.create(cart=cart)
        #           self.request.session["order_id"] = new_order.id
        #       else:
        #           new_order = Order.objects.get(id=new_order_id)
        #       return new_order    

        def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
                cart = self.get_cart()
                if cart == None:
                        return None
                return cart


        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
                context = super(CheckoutView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
                user_can_continue = False
                user_check_id = self.request.session.get("user_checkout_id")
                #if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() or user_check_id == None:# or if request.use,is_guest

                #elif self.request.user.is_authenticated() or user_check_id != None:     #or if request.user.is_guest()
            #       user_can_continue = True    
            #   else:
            #       pass

                if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                    user_can_continue = True    
                    user_checkout, created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=self.request.user.email)
                    user_checkout.user = self.request.user
                    user_checkout.save()    
                    self.request.session["user_checkout_id"] = user_checkout.id
                elif not self.request.user.is_authenticated() and user_check_id == None:
                    context["login_form"] = AuthenticationForm()
                    context["next_url"] = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
                else:
                    pass    
                if user_check_id != None:
                    user_can_continue = True    

                #if self.get_cart() is not None:    
                context["order"] = self.get_order() 
                context["user_can_continue"] = user_can_continue
                context["form"] = self.get_form()   
                return context  


        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                self.object = self.get_object()
                form = self.get_form()
                if form.is_valid():
                    email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                    user_checkout, created = UserCheckout.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
                    request.session["user_checkout_id"] = user_checkout.id
                    return self.form_valid(form)
                else:
                    return self.form_invalid(form)

        def get_success_url(self):
                return reverse("checkout")  

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            get_data = super(CheckoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
            cart = self.get_object()
            if cart == None:
                return redirect("cart") 
            new_order = self.get_order()
            user_checkout_id = request.session.get("user_checkout_id")

            if user_checkout_id != None:
                user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_checkout_id)   

                new_order.user = user_checkout
                new_order.save()
            return get_data


class CheckoutFinalView(CartOrderMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = self.get_order()
        if request.POST.get("payment_token"):
            order.mark_completed() 
            del request.session["cart_id"]
            del request.session["order_id"]
        return redirect("checkout")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect("checkout")
```

models.py for product app

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().active()



class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #slug
    #inventory?

    objects = ProductManager()

    def __unicode__(self): #def __str__(self):
        return self.title 


class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) #refer none == unlimited amount

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        if self.sale_price is not None:
            return self.sale_price
        else:
            return self.price

    def add_to_cart(self):
        return "%s?item=%s&qty=1" %(reverse("cart"), self.id)

    def remove_from_cart(self):
        return "%s?item=%s&qty=1&delete=True" %(reverse("cart"), self.id)

    def get_title(self):
        return "%s - %s" %(self.product.title, self.title)


def product_post_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    product = instance
    variations = product.variation_set.all()
    if variations.count() == 0:
        new_var = Variation()
        new_var.product = product
        new_var.title = "Default"
        new_var.price = product.price
        new_var.save()


post_save.connect(product_post_saved_receiver, sender=Product)

def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    basename, file_extension = filename.split(".")
    new_filename = "%s-%s.%s" %(slug, instance.id, file_extension)
    return "products/%s/%s" %(slug, new_filename)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

**"Expected OUTPUT"**: I should be getting products that are in my orders(which I am already getting) also needs the quantity of those products

Comment: Show your `views` please

Comment: what is `Variation` here? And what count are you trying to fetch? Is it the cart items count, or does `Variation` has a quantity field ?

Comment: added views.py for cart

Comment: Variation is class in my product models which contains variations for each  Product like the price , sale price etc

Comment: so would that not just be `object.quantity` ?

Comment: No that is not working because quantity is not a field in Cart class rather quantity is a field in Cart Item so according to me I first  need to alter my Cart model to make a quantity field and also that field should be able to go through variation as I want quantity for every variation of a product

Comment: I have added models.py for the product Application

Comment: what based on your template code, it looks like `object_list` is a list of cartitems. Is it not? If not, what is it ?

Comment: Object_list is giving orders list